# Why does having a parenthesis around a condition make a difference?

Tags: python, syntax

Python newbie here. Looking to write a simple Leetcode solution. I did not have parenthesis around the if condition below and it gave me a totally different (incorrect) result compared to when I did. Why is that so ?

```py
class Solution(object):
    def numJewelsInStones(self, jewels, stones):
        """
        :type jewels: str
        :type stones: str
        :rtype: int
        """

        # Input
        # jewels = "aA"
        # stones = "aAAbbbb"
        
        
        # This is giving the correct result
        if (jewels or stones) is None:
            return -1
        
        # This is always giving back -1
        if jewels or stones is None:
            return -1
        
        
        jewel_set = set(jewels)
        
        count = 0
        
        for stone in stones:
            if stone in jewel_set:
                count+=1
                
        return count
```

Comment: because the second is treated like `if jewels or (stones is None):`

Comment: Look at the python's [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 2):

`is` has higher precedence than `or`; `a or b is c` is equivalent to `a or (b is c)`.

Neither one is correct, though; you need to use `or` to combine two explicit comparisons, rather than this attempt a kind of compound comparison.

```
if jewels is None or stones is None:
    ...
```

(Or rather, `(jewels or stones) is None` may only be "accidentally" correct, insofar as `jewels or stones` evaluates to one value or the other, which is then compared to `None`.)

Comment: `(jewels or stones) is None` works fine (assuming the intent is to bail out if they're both `None`) because if they're both `None` then the expression will evaluate to `None`, but if one isn't then it'll evaluate to whatever that is.

Comment: Actually, it's not even accidentally correct. If `jewels == 'A'` and `stones == None`, `jewels or stones` is `'A'`, which is not `None`.

Comment: It only gets the correct answer when both are None or both are not None.